# Mathematics errors in basic C++ program

Tags: c++, types

I am working with a basic C++ program to determine the area and perimeter of a rectangle. My program works fine for whole numbers but falls apart when I use any number with a decimal. I get the impression that I am leaving something out, but since I'm a complete beginner, I have no idea what.

Below is the source:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Declared variables
int length;  // declares variable for length
int width;  // declares variable for width
int area;  // declares variable for area
int perimeter; // declares variable for perimeter


    // Statements
cout << "Enter the length and the width of the rectangle: ";  // states what information to enter
cin >> length >> width;  // user input of length and width
cout << endl;  // closes the input
area = length * width;  // calculates area of rectangle
perimeter = 2 * (length + width);  //calculates perimeter of rectangle
cout << "The area of the rectangle = " << area << " square units." <<endl;  // displays the calculation of the area
cout << "The perimeter of the rectangle = " << perimeter << " units." << endl;  // displays the calculation of the perimeter
system ("pause"); // REMOVE BEFORE RELEASE - testing purposes only

return 0;
}
```

Comment: In case you don't know, you should click the check mark under the answer you think is the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change all your `int` type variables to `double` or `float`. I would personally use `double` because they have more precision than `float types`.

Comment: You're not likely to notice the extra accuracy, though. For instance, `double(1.0)-double(0.9) != double(0.1)`, just like with floats.

Comment: I believe you mean precision, not accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

int datatype stands for integer (i.e. positive and negative whole numbers, including 0)

If you want to represent decimal numbers, you will need to use float.

Comment: or double for more precision. :)

Comment: You could also conceivably use fixed point...  For example if you change the "units", eg. `int Milliseconds;` is not a float but represents a fraction of a second.  As always, the best approach will depend on the specifics of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the float or double type, like the others already said.

But it ain't as simple as that. You need to understand what floating-point numbers actually are, and why (0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1) != (0.3). This is a complicated subject, so I won't even try to explain it here - just remember that a float is **not** a decimal, even if the computer is showing it to you in the form of a decimal.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I know that I need to go back over that section and reread. Any online sources you can think of that might explain it in a way that makes sense?

Comment: @H Bomb1013: I always recommend this resource (http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). It's a must-read if you're new to floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks. I will bookmark that for a read. Especially since I have the feeling it will be a reoccurring theme.

Answer (score 0):

use floats not ints an integer (int) is a whole number, floats allow decimal places (as do doubles)

```
float length;  // declares variable for length
float width;  // declares variable for width
float area;  // declares variable for area
float perimeter; // declares variable for perimete
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined your variables as integers. Use double instead.

Also, you can look up some formatting for cout to define the number of decimal places you want to show, etc.